# c# Fields to include in parameterized constructor, of a class that has derived from another class that has derived from abstract class

Tags: c#, class, constructor, abstract-class, abstract

I have a class `Accommodation` as follows:

```
class Accommodation {
    int accommodationNo
    String address1
    String address2
    String postcode
    double valuation
    double rent
    int noRentPaymentsPerYe
}
```

Class `Housing` extends `Accommodation`:

```
class Housing : Accomodation {
    String type
    int noBedrooms
    int noCarParkingSites
}
```

And class `Flat` extends `Housing`:

```
class Flat : Housing {
    double maintenanceCharge
}
```

When creating a constructor with parameters of `Flat` class, do I include every field up to `Accommodation`? An example of a constructor with parameters of class `Flat` would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I believe it will take 1 minute to check this in IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to include every field, and pass that down the chain of constructors (this is an abbreviation of the fields since only a couple per class is needed to demonstrate - you would need to add your additional fields):

```
public abstract class Accommodation {
    private int accommodationNo;
    private String address1;
    protected Accomodation(int acomNo, string addr1) {
        this.accomodationNo = acomNo;
        this.address1 = addr1;
    }
}
public class Housing {
    private String type;
    private int noBedrooms;
    public Housing(int acomNo, string addr1, string typ, int noBeds) 
            : base(acomNo, addr1) {
        this.type = typ;
        this.noBedrooms = noBeds;
    }
}
public class Flat {
    double maintenanceCharge;
    public Flat(int acomNo, string addr1, string typ, int noBeds, double maintCharge) 
            : base(acomNo, addr1, typ, noBeds) {
        this.maintenanceCharge = maintCharge;
    }
}
```